# Getting the wrong return code from exit() after fork() and wait()

Tags: c, fork, wait

I'm working on unit tests for my little daemon but I'm having trouble getting the right exit code from the forked process. If I only run one of the testcases they work fine, but if I run two in a row the second one fail since it doesn't get EXIT_SUCCESS as a return code. I've checked and the second test case does call exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) so it should return that, but somehow I get another child process.

What am I missing?

```
bool test_setup() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        fail("Failed to fork", PLACE);
    }
    else if(pid > 0) { //main thread
        //act as client to server, this code might call exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    //child thread
    //run server
    int retval; //return value from child process
    wait(&retval);
    return WEXITSTATUS(retval) == EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool test_send_one() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        fail("Failed to fork", PLACE);
    }
    else if(pid > 0) { //main thread
        //act as client to server, this code might call exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
        cout <<"exit success" <<endl;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    //child thread
    //run server
    int retval; //return value from child process
    wait(&retval);
    return WEXITSTATUS(retval) == EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    test_setup();   
    test_send_one();
}
```

Comment: There are no "threads" in your program. However, there is also only every *one* process alive; after every `fork()`, one of the two resulting processes exits. You should rather have a *single* `fork()`, with send and listen code in the two respective branches.

Comment: @CharlesBailey sorry about that, fixed the child problem.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: No, I thought that's what I'm doing with exit() in the child and wait() in the main thread.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Hm...so a single fork() in main instead of a fork() in each testcase?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Aha, it's like that. Yes if I switch if(pid > 0) to if(pid == 0) everything works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @CharlesBailey If you enter that as a answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll answer this myself in a few days.

Comment: Yes, single fork, if child then send_one else be_server, etc. Note that only the parent can do a `wait`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because when I re-read your comments in the code it seemed as though you understood this and it was intentional.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Ah, ok, well I didn't but everything is working now and the offer for answer still stands for a couple of days.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The thing is that I like the server to be fresh for each testcase, so I'm leaning towards keeping the fork in each testcase.

Comment: @dutt: Fine, but you still need to get it right. In that case, you'll have: master --(fork)-> master+client -> (client does its thing, master forks again) --(fork)-> master+server -> (server does its thing, master waits) --(wait, wait)-> done.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Hm, there seem to have been a misunderstanding. It's master -> master+client, client exits master runs on to the next testcase. It's only pending between 1 and 2 processes since the client exits at the end of each testcase. Is that still wrong?

Comment: Forget about test cases for the moment. Just think how you would run one single test. If you need several tests, just run them sequentially.

Comment: Hm...we seem to be talking around each other. I am running the cases sequentially. Each case has one fork, parent running the daemon and the child sending the traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had swapped the if(pid > 0) and if(pid == 0).